# How do I set Set ContentType before upload to azure blob container

Tags: azure-storage, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the asp.net-core webapi to upload images to azure storage.

I was able to successfully upload a image blob to azure storage (using the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)). However, the content-type property (with azure) is set to `application/octet-stream`. The problem with this is the public url will not load in a browser due to this content type. I plan to eventually consume this url/image in my website so I'm thinking this might work. Is there any way to specify the `CONTENT-TYPE` to `image/jpeg`? I've also tried the following code but received error message: `404 (The specified blob does not exist.)` during the SetHttpHeaders call (the UploadBlob method call that is currently commented out does work, but has the octet-stream content type).

```
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(guids[index]);
                using (var content = file.OpenReadStream())
                {

                    blobClient.Upload(content);
                    blobClient.SetHttpHeaders(new BlobHttpHeaders() { ContentType = "image/jpeg" });
                    //containerClient.UploadBlob(guids[index], content);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specific contentType, with the filename.[ext] download ok. When create the reference to blobclient set the extension. Example download:

```
var fileName = $"{guids[index]}.jpg";   
var pathStorage = Path.Combine(path, fileName); 
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(pathStorage);

BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

byte[] bytesContent;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await download.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
    bytesContent = ms.ToArray();
 }
return bytesContent;
```

Example upload:

```
var fileName = $"{guids[index]}.jpg";   
var pathStorage = Path.Combine(path, fileName); 
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(pathStorage);

var stream = new MemoryStream(bytesContent);

var uploadInfo = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
```

Comment: When I upload the file is coming from FormData (Request.Form.files). I am using .jpg extension (i.e. guids[index] = guid.jpg

Comment: Convert to bytes array, bytesContent is an bytes array (byte[])